# different names for a same string in java

Tags: java, string

```
class test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  String s1 = new String("JAVA");
  String s2 = new String("JAVA");
  String s3 = new String("JAVA");
 }
}
```

How many string objects are being created here and why??

Comment: 3 string objects are created.i think interning doesn't apply when you use new operator to create string.

Comment: There are 3 objects created explicitly by you and one for the string literal `"JAVA"` created implicitly and put into the string literal pool.

Answer (score 2):

3 different String objects are declared and initialized to "JAVA".

Every time you call `new String()` a new immutable String object is created.

Comment: but whenever I print the hashcode, it returns same value for all three

Comment: @Brometheus `hashCode()` always returns the same value for equal String values even though they are different objects.

Comment: how do i verify that there are actually three objects?

Comment: @Brometheus you could use `System.identityHashCode`.

Comment: `System.identityHashCode(Object o)` always uses the implementation of `hashCode()` from `Object` regardless if it's overridden. With this you can use the internal memory address value to calculate a hash value instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're printing out the hashcode of each object, but try the following and see what you get.  You should have a different hashcode for each String object because although each object is a String with the same value, they are stored in different places in memory.

```
class test{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1 = new String("JAVA");
        String s2 = new String("JAVA");
        String s3 = new String("JAVA");

        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s1));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s2));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s3));
    }
}
```

That should return a result like:

```
219604438
1514883920
87924608
```

That's how it returned on my system.  It'll be different on yours.

Answer (score 0):

Three different string objects are being created, even though each has the same value. The `new` operator creates a new instance of an object. If you think of it in terms of memory, it may look something like this (assuming the numbers on the left are locations in memory):

```
String s1: 01
01 J
02 A
03 V
04 A

String s2: 06
06 J
07 A
08 V
09 A

String s3: 11
11 J
12 A
13 V
14 A
```

So each string has its own place in memory but can contain the same value.

Comment: What makes each String instance different is not its value but its place in memory.

Answer (score 0):

3 different instances of String are created. "new" keyword always creates new objects. Although they hold the same value, they are allocated to different memory addresses :)